# Why videojs is not playing all the time, it plays for the first time only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video.js

I'm using `videojs` plugin latest one `7.6.5` upgraded from `4.*`(`4.*` was working fine).

I have **simulated** my project working with `videojs`.

I want to display image or video  in the same dialog by changing html content

**Question:** videojs player is not loading or playing everytime(plays only first time), how to make it to play all the time.

**Steps to reproduce my problem:**

1. see below code snippet or go to this codepen link  https://codepen.io/eabangalore/pen/PoPwQjZ
2. wait for 30sec videojs will come for the 1st time correctly in a dialog.

3.dialog will disappear, image will show up.

4. wait for another 30sec now videojs won't load.

**below my code:**

```js
function initializePlayer(){
          var player = videojs('vplayer', {inactivityTimeout: 0});
                  player.ready(function() {
                    player.src({
                      src: "https://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.webm",
                      type: "video/webm"
                   });
                 });
}

var showCloseNum = 0;
var intId = setInterval(function(){
           showCloseNum++;
           $('#videojs_player_dialog').dialog({
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            autoOpen: false,
             width: 600,
             height: 350,
            open: function(){
                 var player = `
        <video  disablepictureinpicture="" autoplay controlslist="nodownload"  id="vplayer" class="video-js vjs-default-skin"  controls muted data-setup='{ "inactivityTimeout": 0}' style="width:600;height:350;">
                <source src="#"></source>
            </video>
                `;
              
              var image = '<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/468x60?text=Visit+Blogging.com+NoC/O https://placeholder.com/">';
              
              if(showCloseNum % 2 == 0){
                              $('#videojs_player_dialog').html(player);
initializePlayer();
              }else{
                $('#videojs_player_dialog').html(image);
              }
            
                
             },
             beforeClose: function () {
                 $('#videojs_player_dialog').html('');
                 $(this).dialog('destroy');
              }
         });
    if(showCloseNum % 2 == 0){
       $('#videojs_player_dialog').dialog('open');
        
    }else{
      $('#videojs_player_dialog').dialog('close');
    }
},6000);
```

```css
video{
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/video.js/7.6.5/video.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.24/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.5.5/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet"/>





<div id="videojs_player_dialog">

</div>
```

Comment: Why you are wrapping open dialog in setInterval? You want to open dialog and play video on click of button is this what you are trying to implmenet? Please clarify.

Comment: in actual scenario, when i click on any assets list(or tutorials) , a dialog will come and inside that dialog that video should play.

Comment: I still didn't get asset list? What is asset list here a button in the page?

Comment: i'm simulating my project, behaviour, there are huge code that i cannot produce here now.

What i want on every interval i want to load video successfully - 1, if possible changing video source -2 (not a priority)

Comment: why i'm not getting any answers? please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to dispose of the player rather than just removing its elements, otherwise you can't initialise a other player with the same id.

```
videojs.getPlayer('vplayer').dispose()
```

Comment: `try{
         videojs.getPlayer('vplayer').dispose()
 }catch(e){}
initializePlayer();`    


you mean to say

Comment: i don't have any upvote to upvote your great answer, thanks for your help

Comment: it won't play a list of vedios. i disposed it but when i click the second vedio it do not play